# Is it possible install WSL or windows terminal on windows server 2008 r2?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to install WSL or windows Terminal to use it as a visual studio code terminal but I only find tutorials for windows 10 or windows server (2016, 2019)... 
I don't know if I can install them or not on windows server 2008 r2.
Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately WSL is not available for Windows Server 2008r2.  The best you can achieve is to either to install [Linux in a virtual machine leveraging HyperV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/supported-linux-and-freebsd-virtual-machines-for-hyper-v-on-windows) on 2008r2, or perhaps using [VMware Workstation](https://www.vmware.com/uk/products/workstation-pro.html) or [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).  Alternatively, for something more light weight you might get away with installing something like 
[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. You can use Cygwin instead. It's old and out of date, but then so is Windows 2008, isn't it?

Comment: @Toni The Question asks "Is it possible install WSL or windows terminal on windows server 2008 r2?" and this Answer says "Unfortunately not". How does that not answer the Question? If you had mentioned that this just repeats what another Answer says, that had made more sense to me.